# How do i update a MySQL table column with multiple line values where filename is the id?

Tags: mysql, unix, centos

I have a few hundreds file in a directory. I'm calling it `/tmp/testfiles/`

The files in the directory `/tmp/testfiles/` contain multiple lines of text. for e.g Typically a cat `filename.txt` would result in

Step 1) Go find this there

Step 2) If you cant find it there, try and take a look somewhere over there

bla bla bla

some more bla bla bla

---

The filenames are the id for these files. for e.g if the filename is 1000.txt then 1000 is the reference id.

So I'm hoping to output the content of these files into a column of an already existing table where the filename is the id number.

So far, here what I've got

1) use sed to insert /n at each end of line and then use tr to remove the lines

```
for file in `find *txt | cut -d "." -f1`
do
  sed -e 's/$/\\n/' ${file}.txt > ${file}.tmp; cat ${file}.tmp | tr '\n' ' ' > ${file}.txt; \rm ${file}.tmp;sleep 2
done
```

2) use sed to add $filename; at the beginning of each line of the files

```
for file in `find *txt | cut -d "." -f1`
do
  sed -e 's/^/'${file}';"/' -e 's/$/"/' ${file}.txt > ${file}.tmp; \mv ${file}.tmp ${file}.txt;sleep 2
done
```

If you're reading this far, in a nutshell..  Im trying to output all the files in the directory into a csv. Which then i can do a LOAD INFILE to my MySQL table.

so i have something like this

```
filename1; "Step 1) Go find this there /n /n Step 2) If you cant find it there, try and take a look somewhere over there /n /n bla bla bla"
filename2; "Step 1) a second line for example purposes /n /n Step 2) i reckon a third line is not needed /n /n bla bla bla"
```

So here's my question(s)

1. How do i use LOAD INFILE to update the column of an existing only when id = filename ?
2. Are there other ways to transfer the data to MySQL?

Comment: This is an impressively badly-written question, bla bla bla.

Answer (score 2):

The thing with the newlines seems somewhat peculiar to me.

I would do it this way:

- Consider that you can transform a file into its hex representation with

  ```
  df | od -tx1 | cut -c9- | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '\n'
  ```
- Use this to put the result in a script building a query:

  ```
  echo "INSERT INTO table (id, data) VALUES "
  comma=''
  for f in *.txt; do
      id="${f%.txt}"
      data=$(od <"$f" -tx1 | cut -c9- | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '\n')            
      printf "%s('%s', 0x%s)" "$comma" "$id" "$data"
      comma=','
  done;
  echo ';'
  ```
- Pipe the output of the script into the `mysql` CLI.

Comment: thank you very much! the output is what i wanted after i made some changes data=$(df | od -tx1 | cut -c9- | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '\n' < ${id}.txt)